# Why would I prefer metaclass over inheritance from a superclass in Python

Tags: python, class, inheritance, superclass, metaclass

From what I've learned so far, metaclass and inheritance from superclass in Python serve a very similar purpose, but superclass inheritance is more powerful.

Why would I prefer metaclass over superclass inheritance? In what kind of case metaclass would be helpful?

Sorry if there is any wrong assumption. I just learned metaclass today.

Comment: "metaclass and inheritance from superclass in Python serve a very similar purpose" - what? No. Where did you get that idea? Metaclasses serve a very different role.

Comment: At the very least it looks very similar for me as someone who just learn metaclass.  May I know the differences?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you've misunderstood. Inheritance is the classic object oriented technique of reusing code by putting the commonly used stuff in a base class and deriving from that.

Metaclasses in a nutshell) allow you to customise the process of creation of a class (specifically the `__new__` method) so that you can dynamically add attributes and things like that. It's a little complicated and in most cases, you won't need this. There are some details over at this answer [What is a metaclass in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/100003/what-is-a-metaclass-in-python#6581949)

Comment: Why would I want to customize the creation process?

Comment: "Metaclasses ... allow you to customise the process of creation of a class" - they let you customize much more than just the creation process. [You want a class `Color` where `Color['red']` works and does something meaningful?](https://docs.python.org/3/library/enum.html) Metaclasses let you do that. [You want a class `Iterable` where `isinstance(thing, Iterable)` is true if and only if `thing` is iterable?](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.abc.html) Metaclasses let you do that.

Comment: Perhaps to make sure that you return only one of a pre created set of classes (e.g. like a thread pool) or maybe (like in an ORM), you create a class with a bunch of attributes for db columns (e.g. date, name etc.) and you automatically get methods like "filter_by_date", "filter_by_name" etc.